# Easy AES in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I need a CORE that will perform AES-128 Encryption/Decryption. I have searched online but have  not found any that I understand how to interface with.

Does anyone know of/have a nice AES core which I can use?

I've already looked on opencores but they don't have many that to decrypt as well and the ones that do are too complicated.

Comment: whoa, why the negative marks? It's extremely common to use a core made by someone else (and give appropriate credit to them). I'm just asking in the hope that someone on here knows of a good one to use....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to spend some money to get an easy-to-use well-documented AES core.  You can probably Google as we as I (I have no direct experience with any AES core) but here's a few:

- http://www.algotronix-store.com/category_s/23.htm
- http://www.ipcores.com/aes_ip_core.htm
- http://www.heliontech.com/aes_tiny.htm
- http://www.cast-inc.com/ip-cores/encryption/aes-c/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found a nice DES encryption block which I've decided to use as the actualy robustness of the encryption isn't important, it's just a proof of concept. Thanks again, Mike

Comment: In that case, just XOR it with the output of a pseudo-random number generator :)